# Meaning of "Do you think it will rain?"

Tags: negation

With verbs like 'feel', and 'think' where negation can be transferred from the dependent clause to the main clause, e.g. "I don't think it will rain" can mean "I think it will not rain," how do we interpret questions like:

"Do you think it will rain?"

Is one asking whether

a) You think it will rain vs "Not" You think it will rain.
or
b) You think it will rain vs You think it will not rain.
or
c) Is it ambiguous between both a and b.

I see many examples of negative raising in the references of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_raising e.g.  Horn, Laurence R. (2001). A natural history of negation. but couldn't find any examples on questions like the above where negation may be considered implicit in the question.

Comment: Just to complicate the question: You could also ask "Don't [do not] you think it will rain," or "Do you not think it will rain," both with the same meaning, and both with only very slight connotational shift from the original example. All three sentences boil down to, "Look, in your opinion, is it gonna rain or not," with the only difference being that "Don't you think" has an element of "leading the witness." (And we will *not* confuse things by discussing "Do you think it will *not* rain"... or "Don't you think it won't rain..." :) )

Comment: Thanks for including these examples, I agree they're relevant. An explanation is that we we're just asking about the main verb, and the negation tends to float around. This would be consistent with the notion of neg-raising.

Comment: Thus, we are asking about the main verb "think" and so b would be the common interpretation. The person answering would then answer back colloquially, moving negation to the head verb. E.g. "I think it will rain", or "I don't think it will rain" (meaning - "I think-not it will rain").  

As I have a background in mathematics, I tend to interpret these a bit more literally at times. My thinking is this that the interpretation is ambiguous between a and b, but closer to b and that speakers just navigate this ambiguity.

Comment: If someone couldn't judge or didn't know if it was likely to rain, they would reply to "Do you think it'll rain" by saying "I don't know", not by saying "no". This suggests the question is about weather, not about thought processes.

Comment: A similar question is "Do you think John will come to the party?" Here you say "yes" if you think John will come, "no" if you think John will not come, and "I don't know"/"I'm not sure"/"maybe" if you don't know.

Comment: I feel like some are having trouble zeroing in on the nature of the question. Would this be an accurate clarification?: 1) Assumption: the binary question holds a potential positive and negative simultaneously. 2) So then, is the hypothetical negative subject to negative-raising?

Comment: And personally, I'm having trouble getting on board. I'm not sure that the "potential negative" held within a Schrödinger's-question is sufficient to imply anything about syntax. I feel a distinction between *implied words* in a sentence, like the "you" subject in an imperative, and *potential words,* which are simply concepts contingent upon present concepts. Which I guess makes my answer "C": To figure out whether the negative has been raised, Schrödinger has to open the box and answer the question.

Comment: @StuartF Definitely possible and a reasonable response given Grice's Maxims (https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html).
The following is also possible (indicating the ambiguity): If we both looked outside and we were deciding whether or not to bring an umbrella, I could say "I don't think it will rain" meaning I'm unsure but not positive. I could also say "I don't know". I think which is a more appropriate response comes down to pragmatics. In one case we need to decide about an umbrella. The other we can be unsure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it may or may not rain. What do you think? If the question is whether asking for information asks for an answer, it does.

Comment: @AndyBonner My thoughts are that this illustrates something like neg-raising, but I think this is more general, and neg-raising is a special case of this idea.

Verbs like think and feel allow meaning to "pass through them", e.g. negation. neg Think x = Think neg x assuming a person is rational. (Think is essentially isomorphic).

Want doesn't have this property, so "Do you want pizza" has only one interpretation. "Do you think it will rain?" has the additional common interpretation of "what is your thought on whether it will rain or not" as the question passes through the verb.

Answer (score 1):

In *"Do you think it will rain?"*, you are asking an open question that can be answered by "Yes" or "No."

The addition of *or not [rain]* adds nothing to the meaning other than a virtual (as opposed to real) greater psychological liberty to answer in the general negative.

However, in current Modern English, it is not possible to answer *"Do you think it will rain or not?"* with “Yes” or “No”.

The addition is therefore pointless as it prevents a direct unambiguous answer. (In earlier forms of Modern English, this **was** possible to answer such questions by the response of “Yeah” or “Nay”.)

The constructions parallels *“May I go out?”* in which there is an apparently implied *“or not”*. However, as it is unspoken, (in the same way that *"Do you think it will rain?"*), the question is taken at face-value and can be answered “Yes” or “No.”

The "or not", nevertheless, has an effect: as it cannot be answered monosyllabically, it encourages the responder to explain the reasons for his opinion.

Absent further, and less common, context, in questions like: "Do you think it will rain?", one is asking for an opinion – no more, no less. The reply - "Yes" or "No" creates a conversation that is the minimum required for an exchange of information and, as such is neither ambiguous or inefficient.